# Where is the Type class?

Tags: vb.net

i just started learning vb.net.
But i couldnt find out where the System.Type class is.
I googled, but couldnt find any answers.
Here is what i did:

```
Module m
Sub Main(ByVal e as String())
Dim ass as Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(e(0))
Dim assobj as Type() = ass.GetTypes()
For Each m As Type In assobj
Console.WriteLine(m.Name)
next
```

I changed the directory to C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727> and supplied System.dll as argument
But i couldnt find Type class

So,where is the Type class??

If anything is wrong,ignore my ignorance.
Thank you.

Hello again,
i got another problem,this whole thing i mentioned above is about making a console app similar to java's javap.exe utility

if you give the class fullname as argument then it should print substantial info about the class.

the problem is - how do i know which .dll file to load depending upon the class name i give as input???(this is the reason why i expected System.Type would be in System.dll file)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx says it's in **mscorlib.dll**. Does that help? Otherwise, what do you mean by "where is"?

Comment: thanks for the link.. i meant - if it is'nt in System.dll then which else .dll file could it be in.Now i know its in mscorlib.dll.

Comment: @user1247808 on StackOverflow, generally when answers are helpful you upvote them, then you select one that you believe is "THE Answer" and you mark it with the green checkmark to set this questions as "answered"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used ILSpy (free tool) to have a look. It is in the mscorlib.dll

Answer (score 2):

Like Michal and Mr Lister stated it's in mscorlib.dll.

I found it a different way though, if take your code

```
Dim assobj as Type() = ass.GetTypes()
```

and right click on the word Type and press "Go To Definition" (shortcut key F12)

The default display is slightly different for VB.net & C#. (For me anyway)

For VB.Net:

You'll see the Object Browser, you can notice that the Type is a Member of System
 [image: Definition of Type in Object Browser]

If you click on System you'll notice that it is a member of mscorlib. If you click on mscorlib, then you can see where the DLL is actually stored.

[image: Definition of System in Object Browser]

---

If you are using C# then you will see:

```
#region Assembly mscorlib.dll, v4.0.30319
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\mscorlib.dll
#endregion

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;

namespace System
{
    // Summary:
    //     Represents type declarations: class types, interface types, array types,
    //     value types, enumeration types, type parameters, generic type definitions,
    //     and open or closed constructed generic types.
    [Serializable]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(_Type))]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public abstract class Type : MemberInfo, _Type, IReflect
    {
        //snip
    }
}
```